# 2 HashMaps VS HashMap contain Pair

Tags: java

During the development of the service, I have a problem where I need to choose one of two solutions

- use 2 hashmaps
- use one hash map containing a pair of values.

Currently I have an option with 2 hashmaps, however I often need to get values ​​from two hash tables using the same key.

```
class C {
Map<String, A> a = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, B> b = new HashMap<>();

A getA(String str){return a(str);}
B getB(String str){return b(str);}
}
```

I am thinking of changing the code as follows

```
class C {
Map<String, Pair<A, B>> a_b = new HashMap<>();
Pair<A, B> getAB(String str){return a_b.get(str);}
}
```

Will it be more efficient on a large hash table?

Comment: Hashmaps keyed on strings are very fast. Use whichever you find more convenient and clear.

Comment: Either way is efficient. As a side note, `Pair<A, B> getA` should be named `Pair<A, B> getAB`.

Comment: Yes i also read Cormen, I am looking for a Java specialist who understands what the problem is.

Comment: If it makes sense to store the data in a `Map<String, Pair<A, B>> ab;` then that's probably faster because it implies that the data is highly related and therefore frequently accessed together by the same key. If it doesn't make sense, then it's probably not faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this question is not so much about efficiency or performance as it is what would make sense. And to answer what would make sense, one would have to take context into cosideration. If the values of the two hashmaps are dependant on eachother and make a logical unit which could be encapsulated into a class then use a class (or a pair if it makes more sense). If the values are not directly related and only make sense at one context as pairs but in another as separate things then consider using two maps.

Comment: Yes, pairs A, B are in relation to bijection, thanks for the recommendation to use a separate class, I was confused that from memory it may turn out to be less effective, but now I understand that this is the best solution.

But the fact is that some pairs may not have a bijection and their number is not more than a quarter.